# Using a Dead Letter Queue for AWS Lambda Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have attempted to follow the documentation about setting up an SQS Dead Letter Queue for my Lambda on AWS but I can't seem to get the errors to pass through to it.

I have a Lambda on `eu-west-2`

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    if (event.desire === 'error') {
        throw new Error('dutifully throw an error');
    }
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Complete the lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

with asynchronous invocation set to my sqs queue `test-dlq`

[image: asynchronous invocation settings]

I've added the following into the role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sqs:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:123456789:test-dlq"
        }
    ]
}
```

(I've previously had this set to `"Action": "sqs:SendMessage"` but have made it more permissive for brevity)

And I've setup my SQS Queue to receive the messages:

[image]

My test case payload is:

```
{
    "desire": "error"
}
```

which causes the lambda to error and add the error to the CloudWatch log but doesn't pass to the DLQ.

Do I need to do anything to route the errors to the Queue or have I misconfigured this please?

Comment: How do you exactly invoke your function?

Comment: Just using the test button at the top right of the lambda function page in the console. I've also tried using the following on the command line:
`aws lambda invoke --function-name testFunction --payload '{"desire":"error"}' /tmp/out.json`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why your DLQ does not work is because using `Test` button or invoking function using:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name testFunction --payload '{"desire":"error"}' /tmp/out.json
```

result in **synchronous** invocations, rather then asynchronous ones.

To invoke your function asynchronously, you have to use `Event` **type** in the CLI:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name testFunction --invocation-type Event --payload '{"desire":"error"}' /tmp/out.json
```

Comment: outstanding - that totally worked. Is there a way of invoking it synchronously please?

Comment: (in fairness i've no idea why that might be useful apart from using the 'test' button)

Comment: @obie No problem. You were already invoking it synchronously when not using `--invocation-type Event`.

Comment: with AWS CLI v2, you must add the following parameter: `--cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out`